# Save hasMany association

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I have an Entity **Card** and another **ExercisesGroup**.

```
Card HAS MANY ExercisesGroup

// Fields
Card = name
ExercisesGroup = name, card_id
```

App\Model\Table\CardsTable

```
    $this->hasMany('ExercisesGroups', [
        'foreignKey' => 'card_id'
    ]);
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->add('id', 'valid', ['rule' => 'numeric'])
            ->allowEmpty('id', 'create')
            ->requirePresence('name', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('name')

        return $validator;
    }
```

App\Model\Table\ExercisesGroupTable

```
    $this->belongsTo('Cards', [
        'foreignKey' => 'card_id'
    ]);
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->add('id', 'valid', ['rule' => 'numeric'])
            ->allowEmpty('id', 'create')
            ->requirePresence('name', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('name')
            ->add('card_id', 'valid', ['rule' => 'numeric'])
            ->requirePresence('card_id', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('card_id');

        return $validator;
    }
    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
    {
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['card_id'], 'Cards'));
        return $rules;
    }
```

I need save ExercisesGroup when I save Card, like this:

App\Controller\Controller\CardsController

```
$data = [
  'name' => 'foo',
  'exercises_groups' =>
    [
      ['name' => 'exercise bar']
    ]
];
$card = $this->Cards->newEntity();
$card = $this->Cards->patchEntity($card, $data);
$this->Cards->save($card);
```

The issue is, I'm getting this validation error:

```
[
    'exercises_groups' => [
        (int) 0 => [
            'card_id' => [
                (int) 0 => 'This field is required'
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

I know card_id is empty but I can't set card_id because I dont saved card yet so I don't know what it will be, I read the documentation and i thought the framework handle this, what can I be doing wrong?

**Clue** Cakephp is recognizing the association because Is validation ExercisesGroup data. The question Is: Why they requesting foreign key instead filling automatically.

Comment: save the card first.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath That's not necessary, Cake will do that automatically when following the coventions.

Comment: @ndm, I checked all conventions and is aparently fine. About the code that I'd provided, can u see something wrong?

Comment: At first sight, the `exercises_groups` data is not properly formatted for a has many association, it should be a nested array: **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-request-data** Also you are using `patchEntity()` wrong, it takes an entity as the first argument, and the data as the second, however there seems to be no need to use `patchEntity()` at all, not if that is all of your saving code: **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#merging-request-data-into-entities**

Comment: the exercises_groups data is not properly formatted for a has many association: Whats wrong? The array style is like documentation examples, including the link that u provied.

Also you are using patchEntity() wrong: Thanks, updated... could you provide an example how it will to my needs?

Comment: Like I said, it should be a nested array, just like in the linked examples: `'exercises_groups' => [ ['name' => 'exercise bar'] ]`. What you currently have is the format for a has-one or a belongs-to association.

Comment: Check your validation rules, they probably require the field no matter what.